# Is a function that takes intervals into intervals continuous?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, continuity

Let $f\colon \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be a function such that, for every interval $I$ of $\mathbb{R}$, we have that $f(I)$ is an interval of $\mathbb{R}$.

Can we conclude that $f$ is continuous?

If not, can we say something else about its regularity?

Comment: Terminology trivia: A function that maps intervals to intervals is said to have the _intermediate value property_. All continuous functions have this property, by the intermediate value theorem. It is also known that the derivative of any differentiable function has the intermediate value property.

Comment: Also look at the notion of Darboux functions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general, no. Take$$\begin{array}{rccc}f\colon&\mathbb R&\longrightarrow&\mathbb R\\&x&\mapsto&\begin{cases}\sin\left(\frac1x\right)&\text{ if }x\neq0\\0&\text{ if }x=0.\end{cases}\end{array}$$Then $f$ is discontinuous, but it maps intervals into intervals. This follows from that fact that if $0\in[a,b]$ and $a\neq b$, then $f\bigl([a,b]\bigr)=[-1,1]$.

Answer (score 1):

Conway base 13 function takes intervals into intervals but is nowhere continuous.
See [Wikipedia, Conway base 13 function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conway_base_13_function)